Advantages of centaurs in space
Based off of my previous question What animal would make the best centaur?
What advantages could using ape centaurs in space have over humans or incredibly smart chimps?
Some that I can think of are the ability to use four "arms" at a time, although I'm not sure this would be a significant enough advantage to justify making creatures that would likely be much larger and require more space, food, etc than humans. Tech level is far future, and the purpose of the ship is colonisation. The centaurs would be used for settling habitable planets for future humans. What, if any, are the disadvantages of ape-centaurs as opposed to using humans, who would be smaller and weaker in comparison? Or, would highly intelligent apes work just as well or better?
(Ape centaurs are a humanoid torso attached to the body of an orangutan or other large ape)

I think we need a bit more detail here - as this question stands it is verging on brainstorming. I think there is an interesting question here - but when you say in space - what sort of space travel are you talking about - current tech, super far-future tech, Star Trek esque tech - as this drastically changes the potential answers.

I agree, size, body-plan and strength become relatively meaningless in terms of strategy when complex technology is involved. Presumably their ships are adapted to their needs, whereas human's ship would be to ours (I include myself for the purposes of argument). In a battle, the ship's capabilities, number, particulars of the environment (like hiding/cover) and the canniness of the commanders means more than body-plan. Can you clarify what the circumstances are without delving into story-based territory? In Kirk Vs Gorn, Kirk won with technology as I recall.

So just a 4 armed ape, why confuse it by using the word centaur.

Questions soliciting open ended lists like this are not suitable for this site.

VTC:Not About Worldbuilding per the [help]. This is brainstorming pure and simple. Per the [help/on-topic], we do not help people write their stories. Per the [help/dont-ask], open-ended questions and questions where you offer your own answers and expect more are prohibited. Worse, VTC:Needs More Focus because you are allowed to ask one and only one question.

Cardiovacular system. Fully vertical creatures, like humans, tend to have issues to adjust to zero gravity, because their bodies are used to being forced to pump blood "up" into the brain and away from the legs, and never quite manage to quit doing that, even when there is no "up". A centaur, especially a simian one, is more horizontally build, with the bulk of its mass closer to the center. A centaur by its very nature would have a much complex cardio system that does not work like a lift, laboriously pumping blood "up", but more like a series of sub-systems that slosh the blood around to where it is needed.
Horses, for example, are very good at using inertia and motion to force their own blood to slosh towards the organs when it is needed. A galloping horse pretty much pumps its own blood and air in the lungs by compressing and stretching itself like an accordion, with each lunge. This has plenty of drawbacks in gravity, hence why horses are so fast but die so easily. But in space, the drawbacks are negated. A centaur can become or evolve adept at moving in such a way that blood would distribute itself where needed, when needed.
One could imagine an ape-centaur swinging along the station with rapid briahial movements in exactly such a "swing-stop" way to pump oxygenated blood into its arms faster, or inversely, moving in a constricted, slow motion like a sloth during EVA, to limit oxygen use.
In fact, this extends into the whole metabolic level, even beyond cardio. In general, humans are persistence machines, with incredible stamina. Horses and apes, (and thus, your centaur) have low stamina but a lot of explosive speed and strength.
In space, endless stamina is useless, as there are no tasks that need you to put in effort for hours on end. One a spaceship, you do a whole bunch of nothing most of the time (physically at least, your brain does all the work), and then occasionally need to explode into rapid motion when something dangerous happens (like an airlock malfunction etc).
Lastly, due to slightly different muscular expression, apes tend not to lose muscle as quickly as humans, even when idle. So atrophy would be less of an issue to an ape-centaur than a regular human.

Body plan is practically irrelevant
Once we are looking at a tech level of "far future" the strength, dexterity etc of biological sapients involved in space travel are irrelevant.  Drones and/or autonomous robots will be involved in conducting any repairs and maintenance around the starship.  Similarly, colonisation activities at the destination will not be reliant on the crew's physical abilities.  The characteristics that do matter are:

How physically large are the creatures?  Big creatures require big spaceships, so a being the size of a monkey is much easier to accommodate than a being the size of a blue whale.
How much space do the creatures require?  The K'kree (coincidentally "centaurs" in the Traveller RPG) are claustrophobic herd creatures.  They need much more living space in their spaceships for mental comfort, not just the slightly larger amount proportional to their size.  We do not know what level of claustrophobia the ape-centaurs have compared to humans, so we do not know which requires more space.  In short, the combination of psychological and physical aspects of space required for comfort is only slightly related to body plan, especially if VR / "holodecks" allow spaces to seem much larger.
How well do they socialise in small groups for prolonged periods?  With nothing specified about the propulsion method, it's unclear if the (presumably interstellar) journeys to new, habitable planets involve suspended animation, generation ships or some FTL handwavium.  In any case, the critical aspect is how well the creatures work in a smallish community for the length of the journey, which is unrelated to body plan.
How well does their physiology handle the spaceship environment?  Just as the creatures' minds need to be able to handle the environment, their bodies do too.  If the spaceship does not have artificial gravity of some type then they need to be able to handle proloned weightlessness.  If the radiation shielding is inadequate then they need to be able to survive the radiation and/or anti-radiation medication.  These characteristics are also unrelated to body plan.

In summary, while the body plan would be relevant to a 1950's to 2020's spaceship crew, factors totally unrelated to body plan are far more important for a crew in the far future.
